# React Day Picker: How to disable interaction with disabled dates in "Select Multiple dates"

Tags: reactjs, react-day-picker

How can I disable click on dates in ["Selecting multiple dates"](http://react-day-picker.js.org/examples/selected-multiple).

Inside my render,

```
<DayPicker selectedDays={this.state.selectedDays} onDayClick={this.handleMultiDayClick} disabledDays={{ before: this.state.currentDay }} />
```

I am able to disable days but if I click on disabled dates then they are also added in the state.

I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you not simply check for disabled dates in your onclick handler and exclude the disabled dates from your selectedDays state object?

```
handleMultiDayClick(e) {
  // check here for disabled dates
  if(!disabledDate) {
    this.setState({selectedDays: this.state.selectedDays.push(newDate).slice(0)})
  }
}
```